# Show if $A$ is open w.r.t to $d_1$ and $d_2$ then $A$ is also open w.r.t $D$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d_1$, $d_2$ and $D$, given by $D(x,y)=\max\{d_1(x,y),d_2(x,y)\}$, be metrics on $M$. Assume $A\subseteq M$. Show if $A$ is open w.r.t at least one of $d_1$ and $d_2$ then $A$ is also open w.r.t $D$.

---

**CASE 1** Let $x,y \in A$. Assume $A=A^\circ$ w.r.t $d_1$ and $D=d_1$,  then

$$
A^\circ = \{ x \in A| \exists r >0: K_1(x,r) \subseteq A  \}=
\\
\{ x \in A| \exists r >0: \{y: d_1(x,y) < r\} \subseteq A  \} =
\\
\{ x \in A| \exists r >0: \{y: D(x,y) < r\} \subseteq A  \}
$$

Last equality follows from the assumption $D=d_1$.

**CASE 2**
Let $x,y \in A$. Assume $A=A^\circ$ w.r.t $d_1$ and $D=d_2$,...

*I'm stuck here*

Please give some good hints or suggestions for a solution.

Kind regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "$D = d_1$" in the first case?

Comment: $D(x,y)=\max\{d_1(x,y),d_2(x,y)\}=d_1(x,y)$ @Omnomnomnom

Comment: It seems as though that you're assuming that one of the following 2 possibilities must occur. Either for all $x,y \in M$, we have $d_1(x,y) \geq d_2(x,y)$ or for all $x,y \in M$, we have $d_1(x,y) \leq d_{2}(x,y)$.  Do you see that this does not necessarily hold?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out! I see your point @Omnomnomnom

Comment: More generally, for $i\in \{1,2\}$ let $T_i$ be the topology on $M$ generated by the metric $e_i.$  If $k>0 $ and $e_1(x,y)\le k\cdot e_2(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in M$ then $T_1\subseteq T_2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For a metric $d$, $r> 0$, and $x \in M$, let $B^d_r(x) = \{y : d(x,y) < r\}$. That is, $B^d_r(x)$ is the open (with respect to $d$) ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

The statement "$A$ is open with respect to $d_1$" means that for any $a \in A$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $B^{d_1}_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq A$. Using this statement, we want to conclude that for any $a \in A$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $B^{D}_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq A$.

This becomes a much easier task if we first show that $B^D_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq B^{d_1}_{\epsilon}(a)$.

Comment: what is $d$ in the hint?

Comment: The first $d$ refers to any metric over $M$. In other words, 
$$
B^{d_1}_r(x) = \{y : d_1(x,y) < r\}, \quad B^D_r(x) = \{y : D(x,y) < r\}.
$$

Comment: alright, got it.

Comment: $$
B_{r}^{D}(x)=\{y: D(x, y)<r\} = \{y: d_1(x, y)<r \land d_1(x, y)<r \} = B_{r}^{d_{1}}(x) \cap B_{r}^{d_{2}}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{d_{1}}(x),B_{r}^{d_{2}}(x)
$$

Are we done?

Comment: This is a very short way to do it. Just want to make sure: are we done? :)

Comment: @Xenusi You have correctly proved that $B^D_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}^{d_1}(a)$. Now, do you see why we can conclude that "if $A$ is open wrt $d_1$, then $A$ is open wrt $D$"?

Comment: $B_{\epsilon}^{D}(a) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}^{d_{1}}(a) \subseteq A$, right ?:)

Comment: @Xenusi You'll want to put some more words around that when you write up a formal answer, but that's the main idea. Like many intoductory problems in an analysis course, the solution to this problem is very short once we have understood all of the definitions.

Comment: Since $A$ is open there exists an open $\epsilon$-ball around each point in $A$ which  is contained in $A$. Meaning: $B_{\epsilon}^{d_{1}}(a) \subseteq A$ This is just the definition of an open set. Since we have showed that $B_{\epsilon}^{D}(a) \subseteq B_{\epsilon}^{d_{1}}(a)$ it follows per assumption that $B_{\epsilon}^{D}(a) \subseteq A$. **Right**?:D

Comment: @Xenusi Right, so now you have a complete proof.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I have a good understanding of this now :D

Comment: We forgot the case $A=Ø$!

Comment: @Xenusi You could say that everything you said in the proof technically (though "vacuously") applies to the $A = \emptyset$ case.

Comment: So "Especially, it follows for A=Ø ". But I probably how to do some thinking to realise this. Ø is empty, so it does not hold any points... So $\emptyset = \emptyset^\circ$.

Comment: @Xenusi I think a much more practical approach (rather than trying to think all this through) is to start the proof with "if $A$ is the empty set, then it is necessarily open (relative to any metric). Therefore, the statement holds. Otherwise...." then proceed with the proof

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show $$\{y\in M: D(x,y)<r\} \subseteq \{y \in M: d_1(x,y)<r\} \cap \{y \in M: d_2(x,y)<r\}$$